# How to control an LED using C# over the USB

Tags: c#, usb, hardware, microcontroller, led

I would like to control an led strip through the usb port. I have the schematics for using a PIC microcontroller(18f series) and interfacing it with the usb port. I understand that Microchip libraries will make it easier for me to do this. The only problem is I can't find them. The functions performed by the interface are ..

> The LED glows when I click a button on the screen. 
>   The LEd stops glowing when I click another button.

Here , I'm planning to replace the one LED with an LED strip. 
Like there are libraries for programming for android  I need a link to the libraries that provide me with methods that can send data over the usb port .